# replace %20 with dash from url for seo shows error "Object not found"

Tags: .htaccess

here is my `.htaccess` code in which i am facing some problems in replacing `%20` with dash(-). When i remove the code line `" RewriteRule ^(.*)$ category.php?edit=$1 [L] "` , then in url dash appears but the page shows an error that **"Object not found!"** and when the code line `" RewriteRule ^(.*)$ category.php?edit=$1 [L] "` is available, then the page appears but the url displayed with `%20`. I want to remove this problem.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ category.php?edit=$1 [L]

RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*)$" /$1-$2 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*\s+.*)$" $1-$2 [L]
```

Can any one help me to solve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write these rules in `.htaccess` file to replace `%20` with `dash(-)`.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ category.php?edit=$1 [L]

RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*)$" /$1-$2 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*\s+.*)$" $1-$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-{2,}(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181473/discussion-on-answer-by-gufran-hasan-replace-20-with-dash-from-url-for-seo-show).